# AWK. Filtering by pattern from variable with spaces

Tags: parsing, awk, grep

A have problem. I have something like this : (output from command last)

```
user123  pts/18       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/12       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/11       workstation Fri Aug 12 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/10       workstation Fri Aug 12 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/7        workstation Fri Aug 11 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/5        workstation Fri Aug 11 07:34   still logged in
```

I want to filtering by today date

```
v_data=`date +%c | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`
```

next

```
last | head -n 30 | grep user123 | grep $v_data
```

and I get error

```
grep: Aug: No such file or directory
grep: 13: No such file or directory
```

i tried to awk

```
last | head -n 30 | grep user123 | awk -v v1=$v_data '/v1/'
```

and still nothing

What can I do ?

Comment: `last | head -n 30 | grep user123` does not give any output, so grep and awk has not data to process.

Answer (score 1):

First use `date` to obtain the exact same format as that of the `last` output:

```
$ date +'%a %b %d'
Fri Aug 13
```

and `grep` that:

```
last | head -n 30 | grep "user123.*$(date +'%a %b %d')"
```

As noticed by Ed this could also match lines about usernames containing `user123` like, for instance, `user1234`. If this could happen we must use a more specific regular expression:

```
last | head -n 30 | grep "^user123 .*$(date +'%a %b %d')"
```

(`^` matches the beginning of the line).

But of course, if you don't have matching lines in the 30 first lines of the `last` output, it is absolutely normal that you do not see anything. So check first that you do have lines like:

```
user123 <something> Fri Aug 13 <something>
```

in the unfiltered output of `last`.

Comment: Absolutely right. I reused as much as possible of the original solution of the OP, but indeed, it could fail. I integrate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk as a complete solution:

```
awk '$1=="user123" && NR <=30 { if (match($0,strftime("%a %b %d",systime()))) { print } }' <(last)
```

Redirecting the output of last back into awk. If the first space delimited field is equal to "user123", check to see of the line contained the current date formatted as e.g. "Fri Aug 13" If it does, print the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy/paste your command `last | head -n 30 | grep user123 | grep $v_data` into http://shellcheck.next it'll tell you what's wrong with it.

To just print lines that contain your date is:

```
$ grep "$(date +'%a %b %d')" file
user123  pts/18       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/12       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
```

but to robustly print the lines for a specific user+date combination from the first 30 lines of piped input (i.e. output of `last`) is:

```
$ last | awk -v d="$(date +'%a %b %d')" -v u='user123' '($1==u) && (($4" "$5" "$6)==d){print} NR==30{exit}'
user123  pts/18       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
user123  pts/12       workstation Fri Aug 13 07:34   still logged in
```